# how to wrap the data into multi line in grid in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I bind my grid to database. My grid displays the large string in a single line but I want to display the string in new line if it is too lengthy. I tried all possibilities but nothing works. please tell me where I have made mistake.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Procedure_Name"  ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
       <ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="200px" />
       <ItemTemplate>
           <%# Eval("Procedure_Name").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br/>")%>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
<%# Eval("Procedure_Name").ToString().Replace(vbcrlf,"<br/>")%>
```

Edited,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Procedure_Name" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="600"> 
    <ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="200px" /> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <div style="width:800px; overflow: scroll;"> 
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_target" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Procedure_Name") %>' CssClass="paraGraphtext" Width="800" ></asp:Label> 
        </div> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: actually wat 'vbcrlf' represents?  I got error when using this.

Comment: When I bind 'Procedure_Name' in Label the string goes beyond the width of the label. But I want it in next/new line

Comment: Well, may be you can use div tag with fixed width and add content inside that.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Procedure_Name"  ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="600">
      <ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="200px"  />
      <ItemTemplate>
                               <div style="width:800px;">
    <asp:Label  ID="lbl_target" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Procedure_Name") %>' CssClass="paraGraphtext" Width="800"  ></asp:Label>
  </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>